# Improve workflow for converting a deleted answer into a comment

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, deleted-answers, convert-to-comment

I was trying to convert a deleted answer to a comment via the moderator menu for the post. That didn't work, I get a message

> answer deleted; can't be converted to comment

[image]

Because a (non-deleted) answer ends up deleted after the conversion, I'm not sure that this should prevent me from converting it to a comment, but if that is somehow not technically feasible, it's perhaps better to disable the option entirely, just like 'Move comments to chat' in the screenshot?

Comment: If the answer was deleted by its owner and  was not upvoted/appreciated by the community,  is it ethical for a moderator  to  undelete it (even if it's been converted into a comment)?

Comment: I mean,  what's to stop a moderator converting any deleted answer when the OP decided to no longer put their "username" next to it? I might, however, understand the utility if the post had earned several upvotes. P.S. I realise my observation is unrelated to the request but I was struck by the situation described.

Comment: @Mari-LouAСлаваУкраїні that could be worth a new question (though how often would that happen?) I sometimes convert an answer deleted in the LQP review queue to a comment, that's where this would come up.